# VBA - Variable not set 91 runtime error on second loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, runtime-error

I am attempting to write a macro to loop through variable ranges in a column to evaluate if a cell within the range contains a specific text. If yes, a formula(1) is entered in a related cell. If Nothing, a formula(2) is entered in a related cell. Then it shall loop to find the next range.

Here is my code -

```
`Sub ClassifyStims()

'Declare
Dim stimon As Range
Dim stimoff As Range
Dim InspStart As Range
Dim lastcell As Range
Dim searchrange As Range
Dim evalrng As Range

'Find worksheet length
Set lastcell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
'MsgBox (numrows)

Columns("AA:AA").Select
Set stimon = Selection.Find(What:="stimon", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
Do
'set search range from current stimonset to the end of the worksheet
Set searchrange = Cells.Range(stimon.Address, lastcell.Address)
searchrange.Select
'look for stimon and set range variable
Set stimon = Selection.Find(What:="stimon", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
'debug--
'MsgBox ("StimOn=" & stimon.Rows.Address)
'debug--

'look for stimoff and set variable range
Set stimoff = Selection.Find(What:="stimend", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
'debug--
'MsgBox (stimoff.Rows.Address)
'debug--

'it appears to break **here** on the second loop
'set/select stimrange
Set evalrng = Cells.Range(stimon.Address, stimoff.Address)
evalrng.Select
   
'debug--
'MsgBox (selectrange.Address)
'debug--

'look for inspstart within the stimrange
Set InspStart = Selection.Find(What:="InspStart", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
     
     If InspStart Is Nothing Then
     'is no inspstart is present, then calculate B(N+1)
     ActiveSheet.Range("AG" & stimon.Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=LEFT(RC[-2],SEARCH(""B"",RC[-2]))&(MID(RC[-2],SEARCH(""B"",RC[-2])+1,LEN(RC[-2])-SEARCH(""B"",RC[-2])-1)+1)"
     'is inspstart is present, use current breath B(N)
     Else
     ActiveSheet.Range("AG" & stimon.Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=RC[-2]&RIGHT(RC[-6],LEN(RC[-6])-SEARCH(""StimOnset"",RC[-6])+1)"
     End If
        
searchrange.Select
Selection.Find(What:="stimon", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

'Selection.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate

Set stimon = ActiveCell
Loop

End Sub
```

It appears to be working on the first loop, but I'm getting a 91 runtime error when it tries to loop through a second time. I haven't explicitly released the object...I thought I solved it by resetting the entire search range (ie column range until blank cell) and the active cell, but it reared its ugly head once again and I'm having trouble staring at the same lines. Any help is appreciated. *disclaimer I'm not a professional coder by any stretch, suggestions/learning opportunities welcomed.

Comment: You are relying on whatever sheet is active, which is a bad idea because that can change as it runs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Please note that your code has an endless loop because there is no code line to exit or stop the "Do" loop.

Comment: @braX that thread on select makes me want to throw the whole thing out and start again... thank you for sharing and I'll do some tidying for sure after this deadline...I think to start I need to define my active sheet and workbook so I can merge into the advice re: stopping my do loop...

Comment: @taller I assumed it was an object variable error instead of the With Block (the two 91 error indications), but you make a good point... setting the ranges within the Do Loop do little to define the overarching range for the loop. I am going to try to figure out the structure to imbed my Do Loop in a With block...again, novice here :) Will report back, thank you!

Comment: Yeaaahp you were both right. It's still a little clunky (I've got seven circles of Select functions to wade through per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba, but resetting the active cell to the correct column (via Select, keeping the method consistent for now) and imbedding my loop in a With block has it working at least initially. Thank you both for your advice!